# Trouble using antispambot()

Tags: functions, email

I have a custom field in a theme that contains an email address and was pleased to find `antispambot()`

```
<p><a href="mailto:<?php antispambot(the_field('queries_e-mail')); ?>"> <?php echo antispambot(the_field('queries_e-mail'));?></a></p>
```

It looks fine and works as intended (ie. it opens a compose mail window) but when I view the code source it doesn't appear to be encoded.

```
<p><a href="mailto:john.doe@mysite.com"> john.doe@mysite.com</a></p>
```

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/antispambot) the default usage is :

```
<?php echo antispambot("john.doe@mysite.com"); ?>
```

which should output:

```
&#106;&#111;h&#110;&#46;&#100;&#111;&#101;&#64;mysit&#101;.&#99;&#111;&#109;
```

However the encoding doesn't appear to be working in my case.

Comment: I'm curious how effective this method actually is. I realize that it's a couple more steps to decode the email address on a page, but a spam bot empowered with some regular expressions tied to popular validation patterns could circumvent this whole function and implementation altogether. The likelihood and nature of spam bots wouldn't put this out of the realm of possibility.

Comment: I usually only use this when a client insists on having the email visible on the front end of the site but I haven't had requests to remove the emails so it must work to some extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is **echo** *vs* **return**,

i.e. that you are using `the_field` instead of `get_field`.

What you're trying to do is similar to this:

```
 antispambot( echo( 'john.doe@mysite.com' ) )
```

but `echo` returns nothing.

Please try:

```
<?php $email = antispambot( get_field( 'queries_e-mail' ) ); ?>

<p>
    <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email; ?>"> 
        <?php echo $email; ?>
    </a>
</p>
```